# Is it possible to reference XAML files outside project in Avalonia?

Tags: c#, xaml, .net-core, avaloniaui

So I have a XAML file outside my Avalonia project called `Base.xaml` that stores a `Styles` object. I want to use `StyleInclude` to reference it in my `MainWindow.xaml` file, **without adding it to my project**, but:

- When I use a relative path (`<StyleInclude Source="..\Base.xaml" />`) it says that this URI can't be parsed.
- When I use an absolute path (`<StyleInclude Source="C:\Base.xaml" />`) the `StyleInclude` object returns `null` and throws `NullReferenceException` when there's a control in the window.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the file into your project with

```xml
<EmbeddedResource Include="../path/to/xaml.xml">
   <LogicalName>ext.base.xaml</LogicalName>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

Then you should be able to consume it via `<StyleInclude Source="resm:ext.base.xaml"/>`

Comment: I forgot to say that I wanted to use the XAML file without including it into the project, to make a Loose XAML system.

Comment: XAML is being compiled to MSIL during the build process and becomes an integral part of your dll. There is a runtime XAML loader, but it works only for single compilation units